# Adding radio to the car

Tags: mobile, power-supply, safety, anytone

I got an anytone 778uv that I want to add to my car.
I'm looking at adding it with a add a fuse to an open fuse slot, however I see many people just saying to add it to a chassis bolt.
I am new to both ham and adding accessories to a vehicle.
Has anyone added a radio with an add a fuse? If so what's the best place to add the ground wire?
I am not interested in drilling holes in anything just yet

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!  I found a similar question that was asked before: [Should I ground my radio to the chassis or battery for a mobile install?](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/4951/should-i-ground-my-radio-to-the-chassis-or-battery-for-a-mobile-install)  Does this answer your question?  Also there is lots of great information for hams using radios in their cars at [k0bg.com](https://www.k0bg.com/).

Comment: I did see this thread earlier, no one in here seems to answer the question of grounding to the chassis. It seems like they only speak of grounding through options in the engine bay. I understand that this is probably the best and preferred method. However I'm not sure I want to keep this radio along with drilling holes in the firewall for the cabling

Answer (score 1):

That is a nice radio. Your best ground is at the alternator, but most of the time that is not easily accessible. The next would be the Chassis and finally the Battery. Reason for this order is the Ground of the power source (alternator) is connected to the chassis (Typically the engine block) which is also connected to the battery -. You can toggle between three different power levels, ranging from 5W through to 15W, all the way up to a maximum of 25W. My advice is to size wire for double the maximum or more. This helps it maintain stability.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an existing bolt for grounding, ex. a seat bolt or center console mounting bolt. You do want to get bare metal for your grounding though. I have for my last vehicle replaced the “ground strap” with a much more substantial cable as I had noise.